# Basic C2DM application failure

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I followed the official guide how to start and run App Engine Android application from here - http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug.html. But still can't run the generated app properly and getting PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR from C2DM. Quick summarize of my problem:
1. All other stages in the app runs fine
2. I signed up for C2MD with gmail account and got a reply
3. I used this account for all email fields in the app
4. I read the possible problems from the guide, and all looks ok
4. Still got PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR from C2DM

Maybe there's some problems that the guide doesn't mention?
Will be glad to get replies and answers

**Upate:**
My permissions from App's Manifest:

```
<!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
<permission android:name="com.teamagly.friendizer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.teamagly.friendizer.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- Permission to register and receive data messages -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Permission for internet access -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Permission to keep the processor from sleeping -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Permission to retrieve the list of accounts in the Accounts Service -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Permission to request authtokens from the AccountManager -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Comment: Did you give your app all the required permissions?

Comment: Does your device or emulator has email account setup and android market ?

Comment: @Jave -I updated my permissions, you can look at them

Comment: @Rihan - Hey, I proceeded setup that detailed at the guide, kind of binding an email address and a device. I don't sure how it associates with a Android Market.

Comment: Google says It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Market application installed. However, you are not limited to deploying your applications through Market. It uses an existing connection for Google services. This requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used Android 4.0, anf for some reason C2DM won't work for me on this version. When I downgrade Android to 2.3.3, the registration to C2DM succeeded, and the code ran as it should.